# Is this tweepy authentication a user authentication or Application authentication?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

I'm collecting tweets based on hashtag name using python. 
I'm using this as my twitter API connection:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

I have created a twitter account and generated the authentication credentials as shown below:
[image]

I'm trying to know which type of authentication does my account have to know how many requests am I allowed to before hitting the rate limit.

- Is this an Application authentication or User authentication?

I think I'm using App authentication but I'm not sure.

I believe I'm using GET search/tweets (because I'm searching tweets)    which allow me to send 180 request for user authentication and 450 for application authentication per 15 minutes as it is stated here ([Rate limits twitter developer website](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits))

Hopefully I have made my question clear, don down-vote me plz ><"

Answer (score 0):

It is an application authentication. If your application has different users then each will have user auth. I believe you are not actually making this kind of app and are using the API to download tweets for your own purposes, you will only care about the app authentication.

Also, some of the rate limits are soft - you can go above them if it's not a peak time - the 7-days limit is one of them. (I've been able to download tweets for the past 10-11 days). The 15-min limit is hard though.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Yoana G, Actually it's true I'm not collecting tweets for personal purposes. If I'm using App authentication that means I have 450 requests per 15 mins which means I can download 45000 tweets every 15 minutes. I'm I right?

Comment: Not quite. I believe depending on your search method the number of tweets you get per request is different. I am searching for geocoded tweets which allows me to get a maximum of 100 tweets per request. 
   `input_tweet_data= tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = " ", lang = "en", geocode = item).items(10000) `

Getting 10000 tweets takes me roughly an hour. (If 10 000 tweets are indeed available at the location)